# How to handle cancel button of reload site jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using this method to stop webpage from accidental close:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
     return false;
 });
```

I want to show alert when I click cancel, how is it possible?

I tried this but no luck:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
  if (confirm('Are you sure ?')) {
    return false;
  }
  else{
    alert('webpage not reloaded, your data is safe!');
  }
 });
```

Comment: *"how is it possible"* ... it's not allowed. Over the years that event was heavily abused and so it is very restrictive now to prevent taking control of browser away from user

Answer (score 0):

> The HTML specification states that calls to `window.alert()`, `window.confirm()`, and `window.prompt()` methods may be ignored during this event. See the HTML specification for more details.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event

> The HTML specification states that authors should use the `Event.preventDefault()` method instead of using `Event.returnValue`. However, this is not supported by all browsers.

> ```
> window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {
>   // Cancel the event as stated by the standard.
>   event.preventDefault();
>   // Chrome requires returnValue to be set.
>   event.returnValue = '';
> });
> ```

You might consider the following.

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  if (confirm('Are you sure ?')) {
    return true;
  } else{
    alert('webpage not reloaded, your data is safe!');
  }
});
```

This may fail, so maybe consider a `<div>` style popup or dialog confirm & alert. Maybe look at jQuery UI.